# How to use JavaScript to replace any characters found within one string from another string

Tags: javascript, replace, regexp-replace

I'm pretty sure I've seen this before but for the life of me, I can't remember how it's done. I've been banging my head on this for hours!

What I would like to do is load up a series of alphanumeric and symbol characters into a string called "allowedCharacters".

Then, when a userEnteredString comes along, I'd like to do a string.replace() to remove any character NOT in "allowedCharacters" from userEnteredString.

Like this:

```
function parseEntry(enteredString) {
    let allowedAlphas = 'd';
    let allowedDigits = '0123456789';
    let allowedSymbols = ' ()×*+-=÷\/';
    let allowedCharacters = allowedAlphas + allowedDigits + allowedSymbols;

    enteredString = enteredString.replace(allowedCharacters, '');
}
```

I know this is wrong and it doesn't work but I'm beating my head trying to remember how I've done this before. It's been well over a decade or two.

Basically, I'd like to set up a simple string that can contain allowed characters and then remove any single character not in that "allowed" string from another string.

Answer (score 3):

Well actually if you include all target characters in a regex character class, it should work:

```
function parseEntry(enteredString) {
    let allowedAlphas = 'd';
    let allowedDigits = '0123456789';
    let allowedSymbols = ' ()×*+=÷\/-';
    let allowedCharacters = allowedAlphas + allowedDigits + allowedSymbols;
    let re = new RegExp("[^" + allowedCharacters + "]+");

    enteredString = enteredString.replace(re, "");
}
```

Comment: This will replace allowed characters from the string which is not the expected case. It should only retain allowed characters.

Comment: @Arjun Sorry, I missed that.  Then we can negate the character class in this case.

Comment: That's amazing! I tried things like that but I'm very vague on character classes (outside of DnD that is...) :)

Comment: Okay, I'll try this, now! ...5-or-so-minutes-later...

EUREKA!

Comment: Okay, @Arjun that was perfect! I had worked on finding a way, over and over, but I never once thought about the "^" to negate the contents of the string like that!

Tell me, what would you recommend as a good place to learn about regex character classes? I'm a bit of an "old" when it comes to coding and this seems like something I should have learned back in the 90s when JavaScript was first becoming a thing!

Comment: Sorry; got too excited and thanked Arjun instead of Tim!

It's early; my caffeine levels are too low. :)

But I should thank Arjun, too!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this,

```js
function parseEntry(enteredString) {
  let allowedAlphas = 'd';
  let allowedDigits = '0123456789';
  let allowedSymbols = ' ()×*+-=÷\/';
  let allowedCharacters = allowedAlphas + allowedDigits + allowedSymbols;

  return [...enteredString].filter(c => allowedCharacters.includes(c)).join("");
}

const parsed = parseEntry("123dabcd123");
console.log(parsed);
```

*(snippet also available as a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sfy724rw/2/))*

The main bit of heavy lifting is the last line in the return.

1. We first convert the string into an array with `[...x]`
2. Afterwards, we can filter each character `c` such that `c` exists in the `allowCharacters` string.
3. Once we have filtered the array, we can convert it back into a string with `.join("")`

---

**Related Reading**

- [Spread syntax (...) - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [`Array.prototype.filter()` - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array.prototype.join()` - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)